# Sequentially repeated values in a list with multiple duplicates

Tags: excel

I have a long running list in excel with hundreds of plant names.  Each name shows up multiple times throughout the list.  I need to identify the times when any name is the list is repeated in two consecutive rows. When I try to search for help on this topic, I find hundreds of pages on how to find duplicate entries, but none that outline what I am trying to do.

Comment: This is kinda vague.  Maybe make a mockup of how you want the end result to look. Also, can the name be repeated more than two consecutive times? How would you want to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a column and i would use an IF statement to check if they are equal (IF A1=A2,true,false). Then you can filter by True if you need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad i could help. You can vote the answer as useful than. Thanks

Comment: @eyerah you probably don't have enough reputation (yet) to upvote an answer, but you should "accept" it by clicking the checkmark in the margin to the left of the answer if it solves your problem.